# Merge and display multiple rows in a single row using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, grouping, accordion

I need to merge and display in a single row for particular data which has same id. I'm using ng-repeat for displaying data.
Sample JSON:

```
$scope.sampleTest = [{"city": "Chennai", "name":"Sample"},
                 {"city": "Madurai", "name":"Test"}, {"city": "Chennai", "name":"Testing"}]
```

I'm using uibaccordion for grouping data.

Expected Output:
    *Chennai
     Sample, Testing
    *Madurai
     Test

I'll get dynamic json data. Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: kamla did you check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by city name using filter,

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in sampleTest | groupBy: '[city]'">
    <div ng-repeat="player in value">
       {{key}} {{ player.name }} 
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['angular.filter']);

 
       
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.sampleTest = [{"city": "Chennai", "name":"Sample"},
     {"city": "Madurai", "name":"Test"}, {"city": "Chennai", "name":"Testing"}];
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sampleApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in sampleTest | groupBy: '[city]'">
    <div ng-repeat="player in value">
       {{key}} {{ player.name }} 
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in sampleTest"> ... </div>`, you can do `<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in merge(sampleTest)"> ... </div>` if you define a function `merge` to transform the `sampleTest` object.

```
function merge(toMerge) {
  var merged = {};
  for (k in toMerge) {
    if (k in merged) {
        merged[k] += toMerge[k];
    } else {
        merged[k] = toMerge[k];
    }
  }
  return merged;
}
```